# Media Query BreakPoint on mobile not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, html-email

I'm creating an email with the below breakpoints, but I'm having some difficulties with the breakpoints.

The breakpoint below is not working on mobile, actually I used this same breakpoints for another email and it was working perfectly.

```html
<style style="" type="text/css">

body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  }
  img {
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    mso-table-lspace: 0;
    mso-table-rspace: 0;
  }
  td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
  }
  a {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
  }
  span {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
  }
  .ExternalClass * {
    line-height: 100%;
  }
  span.MsoHyperlink {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    color: inherit;
  }
  span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    color: inherit;
  }
  .em_defaultlink a {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }
 

  @media only screen and (max-width: 4ii80px) {
    table[class="em_wrapper"] {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    table[class="em_main_table"] {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_aside"] {
      padding: 0 10px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    br[class="em_hide"],
    span[class="em_hide"],
    table[class="em_hide"],
    td[class="em_hide"] {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img[class="em_full_img"] {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img[class="em_full_img1"] {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_side"] {
      width: 10px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_spc_20"] {
      height: 20px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_gap_bottom"] {
      padding-bottom: 20px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_height_25"] {
      height: 25px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_f11"] {
      font-size: 11px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_height_35"] {
      height: 20px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td[class="em_text"] {
      font-size: 18px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    table[class="em_wrapper"] {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    table[class="em_main_table"] {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_aside"] {
      padding: 0 10px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    br[class="em_hide"],
    span[class="em_hide"],
    table[class="em_hide"],
    td[class="em_hide"] {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    img[class="em_full_img"] {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    img[class="em_full_img1"] {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_side"] {
      width: 10px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_spc_20"] {
      height: 20px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_gap_bottom"] {
      padding-bottom: 20px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_height_25"] {
      height: 25px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_f11"] {
      font-size: 11px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_height_35"] {
      height: 20px !important;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    td[class="em_text"] {
      font-size: 18px !important;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .caption{
     font-size: 20px !important;
     color: red !important;
    
    }
}
  
    

 
</style>
```

Comment: try removing the `style=""` attribute from `<style style="" type="text/css">` tag.

Comment: Are you testing on Outlook because I don't think it supports media queries - see for example: https://caniuse.email/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mistake was from the style tag
I typed  instead of <style="" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

If you have mistakes like `(max-width: 4ii80px)` and certain constructions like `[class="em_hide"]`, some email clients - particularly Gmail - will strip your entire `<style>` block. Use a CSS and HTML validator (there are plenty online), but ignore the warnings about deprecated code (HTML email uses a lot of deprecated code just fine).

Use https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media/ to find out what you should expect.

Then also just use basic CSS selectors like .em_hide instead of [class="em_hide"].

I would also wrap the media queries in their own `<style>` block (yes you can have multiple), because some of the other things only apply to certain email clients, and Gmail doesn't like them. (For example Mso stuff only relates to Outlook desktop.)